# Counts of every 15 min for last 4 days by column wise

Tags: sql, pivot, case

I have this query which is giving me output in every 15 min how many "NO" recieved.

```
select trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') + (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt,'mi')/15)*15)/24/60 as timeline, count(distinct(NO)) as count
from tbl where trunc(rcv_dt) = trunc(SYSDATE -1)
group by  trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') + (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt,'mi')/15)*15)/24/60
order by trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') + (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt,'mi')/15)*15)/24/60
```

Output:

[image]

However i need similar data for last few days in below output format. Need your help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt, 'mi')/15)*15)/24/60 as timeline, 
       count(distinct case when trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') = date '2019-03-13' then NO end) as no_20190313,
       count(distinct case when trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') = date '2019-03-12' then NO end) as no_20190312,
       count(distinct case when trunc(rcv_dt,'hh24') = date '2019-03-11' then NO end) as no_20190311
from tbl
where trunc(rcv_dt) >= date '2019-03-11'
group by (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt,'mi')/15)*15)/24/60
order by (trunc(to_char(rcv_dt,'mi')/15)*15)/24/60;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is is only giving 4 rows. also first row is not giving proper timing.

Comment: TIMELINE no_20190313 no_20190312 no_20190311
0 108 81 78
0.010416667 14 11 8
0.020833333 6 17 8
0.03125 7 3 11